# I need to figure out playfablogin script I cant get the script to run because of one error, So I need coding

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have one error that says "GetAccountInfoResult does not contain "inventory""

I tried swaping words around it did not work.I tried to delete some that dd not work I am all out of ideas I need help.I just sat there now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.